Amazon EMR 7.2 does not support Ganglia?
When I submit spark job using Amazon EMR 7.2, I got exception:

software.amazon.awssdk.services.emr.model.EmrException: Specified
application: Ganglia is invalid. (Service: Emr, Status Code: 400,
Request ID: 18bb8ccf-acb9-4ba7-a5b4-47d7235cb09b)

The RunJobFlowRequest I submit with two applications ["spark", "ganglia"].
It is working if I submit spark job with EMR 6 or EMR 5
Does that mean Amazon EMR 7.x does not support Ganglia?
Want to confirm emr 7.2 with Ganglia

According to Application versions in Amazon EMR 7.x releases - Amazon EMR, Ganglia is not included in any Amazon EMR 7.x release version.
It last appeared in emr-6.12.0, which had Ganglia 3.7.2.

It is 6.15.0 now

According to the AWS EMR documentation:

The last release of Amazon EMR to include Ganglia was Amazon EMR 6.15.0. To monitor your cluster, releases higher than 6.15.0 include the Amazon CloudWatch agent.

